# How to add "Android.testonly="True" attribute in AndroidManifest.template

Tags: android, manifest, delphi-10.2-tokyo

When adding `<application android:testonly="True">` to my AndroidManifest.template, I get : E2312  ..\Android\Debug\Project1\AndroidManifest.xml:34: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'testonly' in package 'android'. It's the same for release.

Is there a way to get an apk with this attribute with delphi ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place it in Manifest.
Instead you must add `android.injected.testOnly=false` in your "gradle.properties" file

Comment: Gradle is integrated in Android Studio It doesn't seem to be the case with Delphi. I've seen this [link](https://github.com/heinrichmarkus/delphi-build-plugin) but it's a huge work just to add 4 word in my project. Perhaps I'm wrong.